# Тип password в material design lite

Tags: html, css, input, material-design

[image]

Когда данные запоминаются, то появляется баг, указанный на скрине выше, слово "Пароль" не исчезает так как в "Электронная почта".

А когда кликаешь по любому месту страницы, то все становится нормально.

[image]

Я предполагаю, что поле "Пароль" выполняет аналогичное autofocus. Но почему и как это исправить?

```html
<div class="mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-color--white" style="padding: 16px 32px">
  <h4>Вход на сайт</h4>
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label"><input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="email" id="email" name="email"><label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="email">Электронная почта</label></div><br>
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label"><input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" id="password" name="password"><label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="password">Пароль</label></div><br>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfNOyQUAAAAAD2d6klijX3jGeSP8xjAKzV2AuKj" style="transform:scale(0.83);transform-origin:0 0"></div><br><a class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdl-color-text--white" id="submit-form">Войти</a> <a class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised" style="margin-left: 5px" href="/password">Проблемы?</a></form><br></div>
```